# Maximize this function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

How do I maximize this function subject to this constraint?

$\max (\min(2x_A,y_A)+\min(x_B,2y_B))$ subject to $x_A+x_B=1$ and $y_A+y_B=1$

Comment: 4/3 is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, $2x_A=y_A$ and $x_B=2y_B$ Solving, you get $x_A=\frac 13$ and $y_A=\frac 23$

Thus, answer is $\frac 43$

Comment: could you explain why we use symmetry in this question?

Comment: The minimum or maximum occurs only in two situations in linear problems - The symmetrical and the Extreme. You can try out the extreme ($x_A=1$ and $y_B=1$) It doesn't give maximum.

Comment: could you explain why this is a linear problem?

Comment: $x_A$ and $x_B$ are linearly related. $y_A$ and $y_B$ are linearly related. Min and Max are linear functions as long as their components are linear. Therefore, the total function is a linear function with respect to $x_A$ and $y_B$.